# Can I get a collection of versions for versionable Doctrine record?

Tags: php, doctrine

So I'm trying to find a way to get a collection of all versions of a versionable Doctrine Record. Is this possible? I could definitely build something that would do it but I wasn't sure if the functionality was already built in.
Thanks in advance,
John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that Doctrine's (at least 1.2 version) versionable behaviour doesn't define any additional methods for your model except `revert()` that allows you to revert previous version of resource.

So you'll have to do everything by your own.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: I posted another way below. You think it is Symfony specific and isn't available in pure Doctrine?

Answer (score 1):

you can query on the Version table:
Doctrine::getTable('EntityVersions')->findAllById($entity_id);

*gyaan*: for any Version table, the PK is jointly placed on the id & version. Unlike default doctrine style, there is no surrogate key!

Answer (score 1):

**I implemented an access shortcut in the corresponding Table-Class** e.g. `model/doctrine/ItemTable.class.php`:

```
public static function getHistoryInstance() {
    return self::getInstance()->getTemplate('Versionable')->getAuditLog()->getTable();
}
```

Then accessing the history like this from whereever:

```
    $history_collection = ItemTable::getHistoryInstance()->createQuery()
            ->select('id')
            ->execute();
```

*(I'm using Symfony 1.4 with Doctrine 1.2)*

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else stumbles upon this: Here is a quick solution how to get the versioned records. (This should of course better be implemented inside or as extension of the 'AuditLog' class, but for a quick solution the following can just go anywhere.)

```
/**
 * get collection of versioned records as array
 * 
 * @param string $table table name without the 'Version' -suffix (e.g. 'User' instead of 'UserVersion')
 * @param mixed $id simple id or array with key / value pairs for compound keys
 * @return array 
 */
public function getHistory($table, $ids) {

    $className = $table . 'Version';

    $identifiers = (array) Doctrine_Core::getTable($table)->getIdentifier();
    if (count($identifiers) === 1) {
        $ids = array_combine($identifiers, (array) $ids);
    }

    $q = Doctrine_Core::getTable($className)
            ->createQuery();

    $conditions = array();
    $values = array();
    foreach ($identifiers as $id) {
        if (!isset($ids[$id])) {
            throw new Doctrine_Record_Exception('Primary key \'' . $id . '\' must be given to access ' . $className . '.');
        }
        $conditions[] = $className . '.' . $id . ' = ?';
        $values[] = $ids[$id];
    }

    $q->where(implode(' AND ', $conditions));

    $data = $q->execute($values, Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY);

    return $data;
}
```